# Como almaceno una variable en .bat extraida de un archivo txt

Tags: cmd, txt, .bat

Hola estoy programando un script en .bat, necesito recuperar el contenido de un txt y almacenarlo en una variable dentro de un .bat

```
@echo off
SET var= "TYPE usuario.txt"
echo %var%
pause
exit
```

Con `TYPE` estoy leyendo el contenido de ese txt y quiero que mi script lo imprima en consola, sin embargo, obtengo la siguiente salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me está devolviendo tal cual el String del comando
Agradecería su ayuda y muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar un For. Este script hace lo que pides pero solo en una línea, la verdad en su momento era lo que necesitaba, habría que modificarlo para manejar los saltos de línea dentro del for.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set SEPARATOR=/
set data=
for /f "delims=" %%a in (OCHOA.txt) do (
  set currentline=%%a
  set data=!data!!currentline!
)
echo %data%
@echo.
pause
exit
```

Comment: Gracias era justo lo que ocupaba